How to take single instance of data and test my RNN?
I am making a RNN model to try and guess the close price of the stock market. Currently i'm trying to test a specific date. The data that I used to train and test the model is a lot more than just trying to predict one date worth of data. I am getting an error code of an unexpected array size when trying to predict the date.
Here is the code to build the model:
#build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=32, input_shape=(4,step), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(8, activation ="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.summary()

Here is the code to try and predict a single days worth of data
# Load the trained model
model = load_model('stock_rnn_model.h5')

# Function to find the closing price for a specific date
def predict_closing_price(date, data, model, scaler, time_step=10):

    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    # Add 1 day to the date
    new_date = date + timedelta(days=1)

    # Ensure the date is in the data index
    data_N= yf.download('^IXIC',start= date, end= new_date)
    dataset_N = data_N.values


    input_seq = data_N[['Open', 'Volume', 'High', 'Low']].values
    print(data_N)
    # Reshape the input data
    input_seq_repeated = np.tile(input_seq, (1, 4, 4))
    print(input_seq_repeated)

    prediction = model.predict(input_seq_repeated)
    predicted_close_price = prediction[0][0]

    return predicted_close_price

# Example date query
query_date = "2024-05-24"
predicted_close_price = predict_closing_price(date, data, model, scaler)
print(f"Predicted closing price for {query_date}: {predicted_close_price}")

lastly here is the error that I received
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4, 4), found shape=(None, 4, 16)
maybe I'm just not understanding the sequential layer or how my data is being processed, but any help would be greatly appreciated
I have tried changing the model optimizer, padding the predicted data array, and duplicating the predicted data in an array. I expected, since im taking in 5 variables that if the data array was looking for a (1, 4, 10) array, I could duplicate the predicting amount variables enough to fill an array of that size and send it to the model. However this netted me a (1, 4, 16) array size and i'm not quite sure why.

Hi @SamuraOTS ,Your RNN model expects input with the shape (batch_size, time_steps, features). In your case, the model's expected input shape is (None, 4, step), where step should correspond to the number of time steps in your input sequence. However, from the error message and your code, it looks like there is a mismatch between the expected input shape and the shape of the data you are trying to predict.Extract the necessary number of time steps from your data and reshape it correctly.
